# How do I get error responce form mail server?

Tags: php, email, ubuntu

I'm sending e-mails to my users using phps mail function.
However some users don't receive them at all (not even taken by spam filters).
In my quest for finding the error I was asked (by the nice people at my users mail provider) what response I get from their server.

However, I have no idea of how to get that.
Should it be saved somewhere on my server? in that case where?
Or is it returned by php? Or saved in an error log somewhere?
Or is there even a way to get it?

I'm running Ubuntu server and use postfix for mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error would be in your mail servers logs at minimum.  What is the From Address  / envelope sender on your mail?  Any bounce messages *should* go to that address.  If that address is undeliverable, then the bounce could also be bouncing.  So you will need to first check and make sure that you have access to the email account specified as in the `From:` header or in the `Return-path:` header if that exists.  If they bounces are not there, you will need to look in the mail server logs, postfix will normally log /var/log/mail.log  but this can be changed, so your config might vary.

Another good way of dealing with bounce messages is to use something like VERP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path) Variable Envelope Return Path.  This way, you can process the bounce messages automatically by looking at the address they came back into.

Answer (score 0):

From php net:

> If mail() encounters an error, it just returns false. To find why, we
>   need to discover where the sendmail command put its error. On Linux,
>   this is usually /var/log/messages.
>
> The mail errors don't end up in /var/log/httpd/errors (because apache
>   doesn't know that /usr/sbin/sendmail returning false is an error), nor
>   in /var/log/mail/  (because the email never got as far as postfix, and
>   no SMTP/delivery error occurred.)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

But you can easily store the result of the email into a variable, it will, like mentioned before, only be `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

you can check that is mail sent or not as below:

```
<?php
 $to = "recipient@example.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

Also you can have alog seprately that stores that is message send or fails.

Comment: unless the Address is local the the mail server, or there is something wrong with the format of the message, or a server issue. The mail command will more than likely return true.  The MTA that gets the message will then try to deliver the message and at this time 3 things can generally happen.  1. a 4xx (temp error) and the MTA will queue and retry delivery, 2. a 5XX (perm error) the MTA will Generate an NDR, and send back to From/RP. 3. Mail is delivered.  All of this happens async, so the php mail function will never see it.